# SQL Query - Adding Values Into Multiple Unique IDs

Tags: mysql, wordpress, sql-insert

I have a Wordpress site that needed to have 9,000+ users imported to set up a Directory Listing. I imported them from an existing MySQL (non-wordpress) database and everything imported just fine. Usernames, passwords and display names (MD5 hashed, but I tested and WP will change the password to phpass on the first login).

Thing is... They have all been imported with a user role of NONE. I need to change this to Subscriber. Now, I can get into my phpMyAdmin and I can see the <strike>field</strike> row value 'wp_capabilities' in the wp_usermeta table. I can see that:

`admin accounts` = `a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}`

`Subscribers` = `a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";b:1;}`

I can also see that there are many values entered into each user_id. Question is? How can I write a bulk MySQL command to add in the value `wp_capabilites='a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";b:1;}'` into each user_id except 1, 2 and 3 ie. the newly imported users?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: just type the command and hit enter

Comment: `UPDATE table_name SET wp_capabilities='a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";b:1;}'  WHERE column=something`.This should update all rows and set the wp_capabilities column= to your desired value, where some condition. You can have WHERE NOT condition AND NOT condition....

Comment: Best idea would be, write a php function to update user meta wp_capabilities in functions.php. Run it once and then remove the function from functions.php. The function should loop the users and check if user_id is greater than 3. If yes, the update meta data.

Comment: Hi @Pranita, this would be ideal! but my knowledge of php is not quite up to scratch to write something like this?  Can you lend a helping hand?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE wp_usermeta SET wp_capabilities="a:1:{s:10:'subscriber';b:1;}"  
WHERE user_id not in(1,2,3);
```

Or

```
UPDATE wp_usermeta SET wp_capabilities="a:1:{s:10:'subscriber';b:1;}"  
WHERE user_id > 3;
```

Comment: Hi @robert, I tried running this one before, but it is looking for the column wp_capabilities.  This is not a column, but rather a value assigned to the user ID. #1054 - Unknown column 'wp_capabilities' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0):

I actually ended up using this query:

```
`UPDATE wp_usermeta SET meta_key = 'wp_capabilities', meta_value = 'a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";b:1;}'  
WHERE user_id > 3
```

Because the table had no data for the imported contacts, this is the only value under meta_key and meta_value for all records other than my administrator accounts.

Can anyone see why this would be incorrect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
    function update_usr_meta(){
    $users = get_users();
    if( !empty($users) && count($users) > 0 ) {
        foreach( $users as $u ) {
            if( $u->ID > 3 ) {
                update_usermeta($u->ID, 'wp_capabilities', "a:1:{s:10:'subscriber';b:1;}");
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action('init',  update_usr_meta);
```

Run this function once and all the users will be updated. Hope this helps.

Comment: and this gets run in function.php?

Comment: Yes.. You just have to visit your site once and this function will run.

Comment: Can you tell me the steps you did. Coz i executed this function, and it was working perfect. then only i updated this answer. Tell me steps in detail.. lets check.

Comment: I opened functions.php in the primary theme folder.  I pasted the function after all the others.  Saved back onto the server.  Visited the site.  When I visited it, no page showed, but the favicon did.  I then deleted the function from the functions.php file and visited the site again.  Site loaded normally, but none of the user's meta had been updated.  Just an aside, there is absolutely no meta for these users as they were not imported via Wordpress, but rather into the MySQL directly.

Comment: because there is no user meta already would my answer below not work, being the only item in the array?

Comment: does ur wp_users table has users with unique user id's?